# Access to data in external hdd from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, external, hard-drive

I am a python3 beginner, and I've been stuck on how to utilize my data at my scripts.
My data is stored in an external hdd and I am seeking for the way to retrieve the data to use on a program in jupyter notebook somehow.
Does anyone know how to make an access to external hdd?

Comment: Building a path by using following coding is needed to solve this issue.

Comment: path = os.getcwd()
print(path)
path = os.chdir('E:\Surveys')
path = os.getcwd()

print(path)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what the issue is without seeing any code. In general make sure your external hard drive is connected to your machine, and when loading your data (depends on what kind of data you want to use) specify the *full path to your data*.

Comment: I am sorry to confuse you, but my jupyter notebook launch from C:\Users\OOO, this location. But I don't know how to make a path from a program I wrote in jupyter notebook, to an external hard drive.

Comment: You have to specify the full path to your data location. Can you edit your post and include some code, this would help to solve your problem. Without seeing what you are doing it's hard to help.

Comment: What are you coding when you say "retrieve the data"?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, but I could solve the issue after searching how to make a path! Thanks to  you giving me a hint of making a path!